# How to resolve Xcode "updating took more than 5 seconds" error?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am running Xcode 12.2 and I have a very simple project that has only boilerplate code and one dependency (Realm). But when I go to contentView.swift and wait for the live view to show up, I only see a spinning circle then an error message saying "updating took more than 5 seconds". The preview just doesn't work. I've looked up a similar question on Stack Overflow but none of the answers helped me solve the problem. Does anyone know how to fix an error like this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check that your `PreviewProvider` for the view has everything that it needs to display. E.g if there is an `@EnvironmentObject` that the view needs then the preview will need its own instance.

Comment: Just found out the fix: I named my project starting with a number followed by characters. Apparently you can't name your projects like so on your project unless your preview won't work. If you name your project like '1derwall', it will show as '_derwall' in your Project navigator and cause problems. Hope this helps anyone having a similar issue.

Comment: @JunsuKim just solved my problem. I was prefixing all my struct's [...] PreviewProvider's with "_" underscore. This lead to the 5 seconds issue. Replacing the _ for letters like PP (which I did) solved the problem and now I'm able to see all my screens again